# JSON data for iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here how I am trying to get the data from JSon in iOS-5

```
    NSMutableDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"VLIST: %@", list);

NSString *vList = [list objectForKey:@"DEMO"];

NSLog(@"List %@", vList);
```

And getting the output:

```
VLIST: { DEMO = (34DL3611, 34GF0512, 34HH1734, 34HH1736, 34YCJ15):}
List (34DL3611, 34GF0512, 34HH1734, 34HH1736, 34YCJ15)
```

What I want to know that how can I get the name of this object, which is "DEMO", so that I would use it to display and then want to get this List to be used for Tableview.

Answer (score 1):

[`NSDictionary` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) has a method `allKeys` which returns an array containing all keys in the dictionary. Or you use `getObjects:andKeys:` to get both at the same time.